Trying to pass page title to a component used in layout Nextjs App
I want to be able to have a custom page title within a component on the layout.tsx
I'm trying to create a next js site using v14 and App routers.
SO far I've created a header component which incldes an image, sign in/sign out options and a title in the middle:

import { auth, signOut } from "@/auth";
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image'
type Props = {}


function SignOut() {
    return (
        <form action={async () => {
            'use server';
            await signOut()
        }}>
            <button type="submit">Sign Out</button>
        </form>

    )
}
const Header = async (props: Props) => {
    const session = await auth();
    return (
        <header className="bottom-1">
            <nav className="bg-grey border-gray-200 px-4 pr-2.5">
                <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center mx-auto ">
                    <Link href="/">
                    <Image src={`/logo.png`} alt="logo" width="250" height="150" />
                    </Link>
                    <div className="text-3xl">
                        Dashboard
                        </div>
                    <div>
                        {
                            session?.user ? (
                                <div className="text-center">Hello {session.user.email}
                                    <SignOut />
                                </div>

                            ) :
                                (
                                    <Link href="/api/auth/signin"><button>Sign In</button></Link>
                                )

                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    )
}

export default Header

I then call this in the Layout as follows:
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Oswald } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Header from "@/components/ui/header";

const oswald = Oswald({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: " - Console",
  description: "Console for  Devices.",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={oswald.className}>
        <Header />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


In the header component where is says Dashboard I want to be able to set this from the page itself e.g. Homepage Contact page etc.
I've tried looking at the documenation but can't work out how to do this.
It seems like it should be a relatively easy thing but I'm coming up blank :/

well the way you have done this the only thing comes to mind is to use the next headers to get the path and then based on that display conditionally something in the header component. but there is no direct way of getting the path inside a server component. you might have to pass it in a middleware as a custom header maybe
